Cancel subscription with react-native-iap
The documentation from react-native-iap say to use deepLinkToSubscriptions() to cancel/unsubscribe. The function redirect to store and I can cancel, however, I can't get the return. I not see how make my code listen if unsubscribe was made or not.
I implementated purchaseUpdatedListener, but it runs only when a make a purchase, to unsubscribe not.
Cancel Screen:
useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = purchaseUpdatedListener(async (purchase) => {
      const receipt = purchase.transactionReceipt 
      console.log('receipt',receipt)
   });
 
  return () => {
      subscription.remove()
  };
}, []); 

const unsubscribe = async () => {
  setIsCanceling(true)
  const connection = await initConnection()
  if (connection){
      if(Platform.OS === 'ios'){
          Linking.openURL('https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions')
      }else{
          const result = await deepLinkToSubscriptionsAndroid({sku})
      }
  }
  setIsCanceling(false)
}

